# Meaning of "Be Mr Late Better Than Late Mr"

Tags: meaning, signage

Not long ago I found on the Internet a lot of different road signs from India.
Here is [one of them](http://kunzum.com/2008/10/22/road-sign-be-mr-late-better-than-late-mr/):

[image: Be Mr Late Better Than Late Mr]

It says: "Be Mr Late Better Than Late Mr". I can't understand the meaning of this phrase. I understand that it's some word play but can't catch the idea.

Can you explain this to me?

Comment: ["Late as in the late Dentarthurdent. It's a sort of threat, you see. I've never been terribly good at them myself but I'm told they can be terribly effective."](http://uk.imdb.com/character/ch0007550/quotes)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is a road sign that is meant to implore drivers to slow down.

In this case, being "Mr. Late" means that you are habitually late. In other words, you are late so often that it may as well be your name.

Being "late Mr." means that you are dead. For example, someone might refer to "the late Mr. Smith" if they were talking about someone named Smith who died recently. (see definition 2a [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/late): *living comparatively recently : now deceased*)

So, all together, the phrase is advising you that it is better to be late, even if it means you are known as that guy who is always late, than it is to speed and risk getting killed in an accident.

So that you can see it in context, here is a photo of another road sign with a similar expression:

[image: road sign]

(from the flikcr of [henrikj](http://www.flickr.com/photos/henrikj/5063200238/), CC by attribution)

Answer (score 24):

The phrase is in an Indian ideolect, so it's not "standard" English. It can be dissected.

"The late Mr Jones" indicates that Mr Jones has died. This is the meaning of the final two words.

"Mr Late" is used rather like a nickname — someone who is delayed and has missed an appointment.

The whole thing means "Arrive behind schedule, not dead", and is an exhortation to slow down rather than be killed in an accident because of excess speed.

Comment: None of the items are particular to Indian English, but I wouldn't expect the light humor to appear on a an official sign in the US.

Comment: @Mitch Isn't "Late Mr" particular to Indian English? I think the British would say something like "Be late not late" and leave the reader to work it out, or "Be a late arrival, not late lamented", but the UK doesn't go in for light humour on road signs -- or indeed, dark humour. However I did find  [this image](http://www.123rf.com/photo_13797920_don-t-drive-tired--road-sign-seen-on-the-highway.html) from the US, which wouldn't happen in the UK.

Comment: @Mitch "Late Mr" definitely isn't normal for US English, it would only appear as AndrewLeach described

Comment: Just to give some context - this sign is posted by [Border Roads Organization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Roads_Organisation), which is an organization responsible for maintaining  roads (often very strategic for defense) in very remote areas. They do tend to get very creative and take a lot of liberty in their road signs. It's not uncommon to see such messages on regular Indian roads and highways - however these are certainly not 'official' signs out there.

Comment: *Be Mr. Late, not "the late Mr. ..."*  You just need the article "
the", quotes to delineate "the late ..." as a phrase, and ellipses to show that something is elided (the reader's name).

Comment: @Andrew: From the little experience I have with Indian English, no, 'Late Mr' does not sound particularly Indian. It does sound weird, but sounds very deliberate phrasing purely to get the reversal to work. A bit awkward but not sounding Indian.

Comment: @Izkata: Right. It's definitely awkward, but sometimes puns are forced. So I don't see it as necessarily something that Indians would say and others not (at least not linguistically).

Comment: @Andrew: I think your answer is great. But I can't see why it's about Indian English. I removed that tag from question.

Comment: It's about Indian/Asian English because that's where that phrase is most likely to be used (that is, least likely not to be used). That can only be judged by experience and intuition though: having worked with English-speakers from all over the world, that's my assessment; and it's supported by the location of the sign itself, as with Cameron's example.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: OK. I just didn't want to make the error of "it's weird so it must be special to the speaker" when it's just "It's weird for everybody".

Answer (score 9):

It's a play on the word *late* which can have [multiple meanings](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/late):

> 1. doing something or taking place after the expected, proper, or usual time:
>      *his **late** arrival*
> 2. (the/one's late) (of a specified person) no longer alive:
>      *the **late** Francis Bacon*

By the above definitions, the road sign can be interpreted as,

> Driving slowly and arriving *late* is better than driving fast and "arriving" **dead**.