# Is an 'ideolect' peculiar to just one person, or are there national/communal 'ideolects'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The OED definition of ***idiolect*** (see below), would suggest it is something personal. but I have seen it used, including on this site as a word which describes the common idiomatic content of a community. It is used like *dialect* but referring specifically to idioms. This post for example talks about  the [Indian idiolect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90510/meaning-of-be-mr-late-better-than-late-mr/90511#90511).

So does the OED reflect the way the word is used or not?

> The linguistic system of one person, differing in some details from
>   that of all other speakers of the same dialect or language.
>
> 1948   B. Bloch in Language 24 7   The totality of the possible
>   utterances of one speaker at one time in using a language to interact
>   with one other speaker is an idiolect.
>
> 1964   M. A. K. Halliday et al. in J. A. Fishman Readings Sociol. of
>   Lang. (1968) 158   A person's idiolect may be identified, through the
>   lens of the various registers, by its grammatical and lexical
>   characteristics.
>
> 1975   R. L. Williams Ebonics p. vi,   Ebonics..includes the various
>   idioms, patois, argots, ideolects, and social dialects of black
>   people.
>
> 2001   S. S. Mufwene Ecol. Lang. Evol. viii. 193   Every new speaker
>   replicates their target communal language imperfectly, starting with
>   the trivial fact that they couldn't possibly replicate all the
>   idiolects of which it is an ensemble and no idiolect replicates
>   another.

Comment: Hmm. "ideolect" does suggest one person, at least to me.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154244/is-there-a-word-for-a-shared-idiolect

Answer (score 2):

Both its origin and current usage suggest that it is a term specific just to a personal way of speaking; from ***idio-*** meaning *one's, personal:*

An [idiolect](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/idiolect):

> - ***is a person’s specific, unique way of speaking.*** Every one of us has his or her very own idiolect that differs from the way other people talk.
> - A dialect is a version of a language spoken by a group of people. ***An idiolect is much smaller — it’s the way a particular person speaks, at a specific time, as distinct from others.***
> - ***This word is mainly used by linguists*** when discussing differences in speech from one person to another. Like your fingerprint, your idiolect is unique. It’s kind of like a micro-dialect. (www.vocabulary.com)

[Idiolect](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=idiolect&searchmode=none): etymology:

> - ***one's personal way of using a language, 1948***, from idio- "one's own, personal" + second element abstracted from dialect. Idioglottic (1888) has a sense "using words invented in one's mind" (from Greek glotta/glossa "tongue"). (Etymonline)

From [Britannica,com](http://www.britannica.com/topic/idiolect)

***Dialect:***

> - ...denotes rural or provincial dialects, often with a deprecatory connotation. A similar term is vernacular, which refers to the common, everyday speech of the ordinary people of a region. ***An idiolect is the dialect of an individual person at one time.*** This term implies an awareness that no two persons speak in exactly the same way and that each person’s dialect is constantly undergoing...

***individual speech habits:***

> - ...that may impede but do not prevent mutual comprehension are called dialects of a language. ***In order to describe in detail the actual different speech patterns of individuals, the term idiolect, meaning the speech habits of a single person, has been coined.***

Comment: It seems like a useful distinction; I hope it survives.

Comment: The person who used the term *Indian idiolect* in the quoted post was @Andrew Leach. So it would be interesting to hear his opinion.

Comment: I think he meant an idiolect within the 'Indian' context, which does not imply a use by a group of people or a community.